# Storing a list within another list in a database without previous information in that list getting lost

Tags: python, sql, database, list, append

I want to store a list within another list in a database (SQL) without previous data being lost.This is one example of values i have in my database `(1, 'Haned', 15, 11, 'Han15', 'password', "['easymaths', 6]")`. What i want to do is store another piece of information/data within the list `[]` without it getting rid of  `"['easymaths', 6]"` so it would look something like  `"['easymaths', 6,'mediummaths', 6]"` and so on.Thank you

Comment: You would do this using a second table, with one row for each item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Though not intended you could join the list by a specific seperator. In turn when you query the selected field you have to convert it into a list again.